# My app displays the name instead of the email

Tags: java, android

How do I make the following code display the name as a welcome instead of the email?
When I change EMAIL to Name it displays `null` instead of the name.
Any help would be much appreciated.

I tried changing email to name, but this doesn't work.
I don't know what else to do.

UsersActivity.java (this is what I want to change so it displays the name instead of email)

```
package com.delaroystudios.sqlitelogin.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.delaroystudios.sqlitelogin.R;


public class UsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textViewName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users);

        textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        String nameFromIntent = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");
        textViewName.setText("Welcome " + nameFromIntent);
    }
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.delaroystudios.sqlitelogin.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.view.View;

import com.delaroystudios.sqlitelogin.R;
import com.delaroystudios.sqlitelogin.helper.InputValidation;
import com.delaroystudios.sqlitelogin.sql.DatabaseHelper;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final AppCompatActivity activity = LoginActivity.this;

    private NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;

    private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutEmail;
    private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutPassword;

    private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextEmail;
    private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextPassword;

    private AppCompatButton appCompatButtonLogin;

    private AppCompatTextView textViewLinkRegister;

    private InputValidation inputValidation;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        initViews();
        initListeners();
        initObjects();
    }
    private void initViews(){
        nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);

        textInputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutEmail);
        textInputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutPassword);

        textInputEditTextEmail = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextEmail);
        textInputEditTextPassword = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextPassword);

        appCompatButtonLogin = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.appCompatButtonLogin);

        textViewLinkRegister = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLinkRegister);
    }

    private void initListeners(){
        appCompatButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        textViewLinkRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initObjects(){
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
        inputValidation = new InputValidation(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.appCompatButtonLogin:
                verifyFromSQLite();
                break;
            case R.id.textViewLinkRegister:
                Intent intentRegister = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentRegister);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void verifyFromSQLite(){
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextEmail(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextPassword, textInputLayoutPassword, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
            return;
        }

        if (databaseHelper.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()
                , textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
            Intent accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, UsersActivity.class);
            accountsIntent.putExtra("EMAIL", textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
            emptyInputEditText();
            startActivity(accountsIntent);
        }

        else {
            Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, getString(R.string.error_valid_email_password), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void emptyInputEditText(){
        textInputEditTextEmail.setText(null);
        textInputEditTextPassword.setText(null);
    }
}
```

RegisterActivity.java

```
package com.delaroystudios.sqlitelogin.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.view.View;

import com.delaroystudios.sqlitelogin.R;
import com.delaroystudios.sqlitelogin.helper.InputValidation;
import com.delaroystudios.sqlitelogin.model.User;
import com.delaroystudios.sqlitelogin.sql.DatabaseHelper;


public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final AppCompatActivity activity = RegisterActivity.this;

    private NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;

    private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutName;
    private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutEmail;
    private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutPassword;
    private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutConfirmPassword;

    private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextName;
    private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextEmail;
    private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextPassword;
    private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextConfirmPassword;

    private AppCompatButton appCompatButtonRegister;
    private AppCompatTextView appCompatTextViewLoginLink;

    private InputValidation inputValidation;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private User user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        initViews();
        initListeners();
        initObjects();
    }

    private void initViews(){
        nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);

        textInputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutName);
        textInputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutEmail);
        textInputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutPassword);
        textInputLayoutConfirmPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutConfirmPassword);

        textInputEditTextName = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextName);
        textInputEditTextEmail = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextEmail);
        textInputEditTextPassword = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextPassword);
        textInputEditTextConfirmPassword = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextConfirmPassword);

        appCompatButtonRegister = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.appCompatButtonRegister);

        appCompatTextViewLoginLink = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.appCompatTextViewLoginLink);
    }

    private void initListeners(){
        appCompatButtonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
        appCompatTextViewLoginLink.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initObjects(){
        inputValidation = new InputValidation(activity);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
        user = new User();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.appCompatButtonRegister:
                postDataToSQLite();
                break;
            case R.id.appCompatTextViewLoginLink:
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void postDataToSQLite(){
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextName, textInputLayoutName, getString(R.string.error_message_name))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextEmail(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextPassword, textInputLayoutPassword, getString(R.string.error_message_password))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextMatches(textInputEditTextPassword, textInputEditTextConfirmPassword,
                textInputLayoutConfirmPassword, getString(R.string.error_password_match))) {
            return;
        }

        if (!databaseHelper.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim())) {

            user.setName(textInputEditTextName.getText().toString().trim());
            user.setEmail(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
            user.setPassword(textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim());

            databaseHelper.addUser(user);

            // Snack Bar to show success message that record saved successfully
            Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, getString(R.string.success_message), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            emptyInputEditText();


        } else {
            // Snack Bar to show error message that record already exists
            Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, getString(R.string.error_email_exists), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }

    private void emptyInputEditText(){
        textInputEditTextName.setText(null);
        textInputEditTextEmail.setText(null);
        textInputEditTextPassword.setText(null);
        textInputEditTextConfirmPassword.setText(null);
    }

}
```

InputValidation.java

```
package com.delaroystudios.sqlitelogin.helper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;


public class InputValidation {

    private Context context;

    public InputValidation(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean isInputEditTextFilled(TextInputEditText textInputEditText, TextInputLayout textInputLayout, String message){
        String value = textInputEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        if (value.isEmpty()){
            textInputLayout.setError(message);
            hideKeyboardFrom(textInputEditText);
            return false;
        } else {
            textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isInputEditTextEmail(TextInputEditText textInputEditText, TextInputLayout textInputLayout, String message){
        String value = textInputEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        if (value.isEmpty() || !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(value).matches()){
            textInputLayout.setError(message);
            hideKeyboardFrom(textInputEditText);
            return false;

        }else {
            textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isInputEditTextMatches(TextInputEditText textInputEditText1, TextInputEditText textInputEditText2, TextInputLayout textInputLayout, String message ){
        String value1 = textInputEditText1.getText().toString().trim();
        String value2 = textInputEditText2.getText().toString().trim();
        if (!value1.contentEquals(value2)){
            textInputLayout.setError(message);
            hideKeyboardFrom(textInputEditText2);
            return false;
        }else {
            textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void hideKeyboardFrom(View view){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }
}
```

User.java

```
package com.delaroystudios.sqlitelogin.model;


public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
       return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Databasehelper.java

```
package com.delaroystudios.sqlitelogin.sql;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.delaroystudios.sqlitelogin.model.User;


public class DatabaseHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserManager.db";

    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";

    private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";

    private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public  void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addUser(User user){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

        db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public boolean checkUser(String email){
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { email };

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
                columns,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null);
        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        if (cursorCount > 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean checkUser(String email, String password){
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?" + " AND " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " =?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { email, password };

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
                columns,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null);
        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        if (cursorCount > 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code above you are just passing the Email as an intent extras to the activity. You have to pass the name field as the intent extra and then call it in your UsersActivity.java

Comment: do something similar for NAME.  accountsIntent.putExtra("EMAIL", textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());

Comment: Please read about creating a [mcve], and [edit] your question if possible

Answer (score 0):

> display the name as a welcome instead of the email

Then put the correct value

You are putting an email

```
accountsIntent.putExtra("EMAIL", textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
```

And trying to get a name

```
String nameFromIntent = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");
```

---

---

To help you with that, try to get this code working

```
String email = textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
String password = textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

User user = databaseHelper.checkUser(email, password);
if (user != null) {
    Intent accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, UsersActivity.class);
    accountsIntent.putExtra("NAME", user.getName());
    emptyInputEditText();
    startActivity(accountsIntent);
}
```

Oh, and storing plain-text passwords in a database should be avoided

Comment: Where aboust do i put this code please is it in User Activity.java

Comment: It doesn't go in that Activity. This starts UserActivity. It also won't work if you copy it exactly. Because your `checkUser` database method isn't returning a User object. Hence why I said "try to get it working", as an example of what you *could do*. And it goes in `verifyFromSQLite()` in the LoginActivity... Nothing needs to change in the UserActivity because you're already trying to get the NAME

Comment: What am i supposed to change get name as this is the only bit that i need to change

Comment: Like I said, `checkUser` needs to `return user` object, not a Boolean

Comment: ive made it return user and deleted  if (databaseHelper.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()
                , textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
            Intent accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, UsersActivity.class);
            accountsIntent.putExtra("EMAIL", textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
            emptyInputEditText();
            startActivity(accountsIntent);
        }

Comment: but now its flagging up this  if (cursorCount > 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false; from the DatabaseHelper.java

Comment: You can't return `true` if the method returns a `User`

Comment: Thanks for your help but ive got it to work using a different way